# Related products query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get related products from my database. In the example below I am trying to get the related products for product with the id of 1. The query should select the information about product 1, (it's type, colour, size and style) and then select other products (not including itself) that has either the same type, colour size or style.

```
SELECT * 
FROM prds t1, prds t2 
WHERE t1.id = 1 
AND t2.id != 1 
AND (t1.type_id = t2.type_id 
OR t1.colour_id = t2.colour_id
OR t1.size_id = t2.size_id
OR t1.style_id = t2.style_id)
AND t2.published = 1
```

The above query just returns the product 1 a number of times. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write this as a `cross join` (because I abhor commas in the `from` clause).  But, the problem is the `select *`.  Instead:

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM prds t1 CROSS JOIN
     prds t2 
WHERE t1.id = 1 AND t2.id <> 1 AND
      (t1.type_id = t2.type_id OR
       t1.colour_id = t2.colour_id OR
       t1.size_id = t2.size_id OR
       t1.style_id = t2.style_id
      ) AND
      t2.published = 1;
```

The real difference is the `FROM` clause.  Your version is selecting all columns from both tables.  Not only do they have the same column names, but the first columns from the product 1 record.